# $2^5 \cdot a^b=2,5ab$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, divisibility

I came across this problem in an elementary number theory book, and I think I solved it.  Well, the question is posed as

$2^5 \cdot 9^2 = 2,592$.  Are there any other pairs $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^5 \cdot a^b = 2,5ab$ is satisfied ($a,b$ are the tens and one representative, not a product)?

So at first I just set up a $9\times9$ grid and sieved the answer (which is "No") mainly by eliminating such obvious answers as $a\ne1,2$, and $a^b\le82$.  Then I quickly realized that $2^5|25ab$, and there are only a select few integers where $32\cdot x=25ab$, for some integers $a,b,x$.  For example $32 \cdot 81 = 2,592 = 2^5 \cdot 9^2$, but this does not work for $32 \cdot 80=2,560 \neq 2^5 \cdot 6^0$ and $32 \cdot 79 = 2,528 \neq 2^5 \cdot 2^8$

So i think that, no, this is not possible except where $a=9, b=2$.

Now that I think i solved it, is there an algorithm for doing this quickly or does it require this sort of analysis for all $a^b \cdot c^d=a,bcd$?

Comment: 2592 is the only one. A simple computer program can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution $(a,b,c,d) = (2,5,9,2)$ is unique.

As [hhsaffar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/104929/hhsaffar) wrote in the comments, this is easily verifiable on a computer. Here is how you can do it in Python 3:

```
for a in range(0,10):
  for b in range(0,10):
    for c in range(0,10):
      for d in range(0,10):
        if 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d == a**b * c**d:
          print("a = ", a, "; b = ", b, "; c = ", c, "; d = ", d)
```

Output:

```
a =  2 ; b =  5 ; c =  9 ; d =  2
```

I initially intended to do few more examples in other languages, but they all boil down to this.

**Edit**

Since the OP stated that he doesn't have Python, and I myself do not use Maple, here is the JavaScript version which should work in any browser:

```
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
      for (d = 0; d < 10; d++)
        if (1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d == Math.pow(a,b) * Math.pow(c,d))
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=
            "a = " + a + "; b = " + b + "; c = " + c + "; d = " + d + "<br>";
```

This code requires `<div id="result"></div>` somewhere in the document. You can test it or change it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G9G9C/). **Beware:** it runs in your browser, and if you make an infinite loop or a to processor-intensive algorithm, your browser may stop responding or crash, thus losing you opened tabs and/or any unsaved work. I suggest running this in another browser (i.e., in Chrome if you usually use Firefox).

Comment: So by computer, are you saying that the only way to verify this general equation is a 'plug and chug' algorithm?

Comment: The only way probably not. This is, IMO, the simplest way. Writing the above, using copy/paste, takes less than 5 minutes, and the execution is less than a second.

Comment: Sounds good.  I don't have Python (isn't it free to download), but I have maple, so I can play around with some maple algorithms.  I just want to test a bunch of different examples, like $a \cdot b^c = abc,$ etc.  I feel like there are a few.  It would be disappointing not to find another number like that, but then at the same time, if it were unique, that might be even more interesting!

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows (otherwise, you should already have Python), you can download it [here](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads). Stick to 3.x versions. It doesn't really matter for the above example, but as you edit it, the differences may become more significant. You can also use your browser to test such simple properties in JavaScript. See my latest edit for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'simple' way of doing this. Notice that $2^5\cdot a^b=25ab$ are both integers. Therefore, since $a^b$ is an integer, so too must be 
$$
a^b=\frac{25ab}{2^5}=\frac{25ab}{32}
$$
Now this can be done by hand very simply. We know that $2500<a^b<2600$. How many multiples of $32$ fit this inequality? This is simple to check by hand, the only possibilities are $32\cdot 79=2528$, $32\cdot 80=2560$, and $32\cdot 81=2592$. Now just factor the numbers:
$$
2528=2^5\cdot79^1\;\;,\;\;2560=2^9\cdot5^1\;\;,\;\;2592=2^5\cdot 3^4
$$
factoring out a $2^5$ yields the choices $79^1$, $5^1$, and $3^4$ for the value of $a^b$. Since $0\leq a \leq 9$, $79^1$ is eliminated. It is easy to check that $5^1$ cannot work for then $a=5$ and $b=1$ and the $2^5\cdot 5^1=160 \neq 2551$.

This leaves $a^b=3^4$. We can also write this $a^b=(3^2)^2=9^2$ or $a^b=81^1$. Since $a,b$ are integers with $0\leq a \leq 9$, either $a=3$ and $b=4$ or $a=9$ and $b=2$. We know the last to be true and the case of $a=3$ and $b=4$ is a simple matter to show doesn't work. This method does not require a computer or calculator and took only about $5$ minutes using simple pen and paper.

Comment: Thank you for verifying my analysis.  Other than the algorithm written above, is there a viable method by pencil and paper for checking the general $a^b\cdot c^d =a,bcd$?

Comment: That would be tough but I'm confident an algorithm exists (not necessarily efficient). I'd need to look at examples to work out what it would be. Since all variables $\ge 0$ and $\le 9$, we could work out what possibilities there would could be based on those constraints and obtain a finite amount of possibilities to check. Since most of the numbers $0-9$ are prime, we could just look at prime factorizations and WLOG suppose $d\ge b$ and write $(ac)^b c^{d-b}$ which may make things a bit easier by helping eliminate some cases. But then it comes down to checking by hand or by computer.

Comment: Nice.  I have Maple on my laptop, perhaps I'll play around with some algorithms like @Vedran Sego.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst It's also nice to change 'gears' and work on Math algorithms. Just remember, it's always easiest to write an algorithm by considering an explicit example with $a,b,c,d$ and use how you approached that to write your program!

Comment: Will do.  I can't check now because I have things to do, but this question from the book I'm reading piqued my interest and now I feel like investigating.  Will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Nothing through 8 digits....  I may stop here as it's getting monotonous.